# android group GPS coordinate by postilion

Tags: android, gps

i have punch of GPS coordinates (latitude longitude) i want to create groups each one will contain coordinates that in the same radius , iam using this code to get distance between 2 points:-

```
float radius = (float) 1000.0;
        float distance = loc.distanceTo(loc2);
        if (distance < radius) 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

but with this code i need to compare each coordinate with the rest to check which one is closest ,which seem insufficient , is there any other way?

thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to keep it simple, checking each coordinate is not bad. if performance is really an issue, than you can maybe improve your algorithm with an order mechanism.

Comment: Are your groups fixed? I.e. do you have a fixed set of points as center of the groups? In this case start simple as mentioned by Johannes. if the no. of groups is large you might want to consider more efficient algorithms, but don't do that unless the need arises.
If the groups are not fixed but you are looking for "clusters" consider a cluster algorithms. Here is a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use a geo spatial index, like [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).
In that case you would first calculate which quad cells are within the radius, and then you only consider the points inside that cells.

But this is some programming, search and understanding effort, so use such an index when a brute force search over all points is to slow.